# How to use reactor.core.publisher Mono<T> or Flux<T> with inheritance?

Tags: project-reactor, spring-webflux

I am pretty new in reactive programming, I am using last Spring 5 Webflux framework and playing with so project reactor. I am facing an issue, I would like to use Mono with this inheritance schema :

Client extends User

I created this method :

```
public Mono<User> saveUser(Mono<User> userToSave)
{
    return userToSave.doOnNext(u -> {
        // Some stuff
    });
}
```

I cannot now use this method with a Mono< Client > as parameter in spite of Client extends from User.

```
Mono<Client> client = ...
instance.saveUser(client); <-- Error
```

How can I achieve this ? Do I try something bad ?

Thank you a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a java inheritance "problem": you need to declare your method as:

```
public Mono<User> saveUser(Mono<? extends User> userToSave)
```

(this is known as a covariant generic type. the guidance is "be more lenient in what you consume", as the rule of thumb consume == `extends`)

Comment: Thank you ! Did it with : `public <T extends User> Mono<T> saveUser(Mono<T> userToSave)`

This is what happen after times without touching a single line of code :)